# Windows run two VPN client at the same time

Tags: vpn, openvpn

I have successfully ran 2 ***openvpn*** client (**VPN-A**, **VPN-B**) in my **windows** pc.

I firstly ran **VPN-A**, then ran **VPN-B**.

But found out the **VPN-A** works fine, but the route requests to **VPN-B** were all timeout.

Anyone can help me? thanks.

Answer (score 0):

So you have two OpenVPN TAP Adapters in Windows with different names?  Is IPv4 set to Obtain an IP address automatically for both?  You the client should be getting an IP address from the server.  Each server should be using a different subnet than each other too.